# Moving to the first non-blank character of the line in vim

Tags: vim, editor, vi, vim-plugin, nmap

I'm having some trouble moving to the first non-blank character of a line in vim.

The usual mapping for this action is ^, but in my keyboard that accent is located with the number 6 key, so I have to press Shift + 6 to get it.

As expected, Shift + 6 doesn't take me to the first non-blank character of the line in NORMAL mode, it just prints ^ where my cursor is, and after I press any other key the ^ disappears and I'm back to where I was before.

I've been trying to map that action to some other shortcut for some time, but with no luck. I tried things like `nmap <S-6> ^` too, but it didn't worked.

Has anyone had trouble with this too? I googled it but can't seem to find anyone experiencing the same problem.

Here is the VIM [documentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_around) for that shortcut, and I would also like to point out that I'm using an apple magic keyboard with "U.S. International - PC" set as the input method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ˆ</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to insert a `^` character, or you can use the <kbd>_</kbd> command in vim which is equivalent.

To figure out how the keyboard layout works, use "Show Keyboard Viewer" from the menu bar. After pressing <kbd>ˆ</kbd>, a <kbd>^</kbd> appears on the spacebar.

[image: Choose "Show Keyboard Viewer" from the menu]
[image: Keyboard Viewer showing ^ on the spacebar]